# File Control Information (FCI) use

Tags: nfc, javacard

I am looking into GlobalPlatform Card Specification Version 2.2.1 (found at http://www.globalplatform.org/specificationscard.asp)

> I am trying to understand FCI (File Control Information) concept and its
>   use.

I tried googling and checking other docs has published by GP but could't find any answer. Could anyone shed a light on this?

Comment: It is defined in the (payware) ISO/IEC 7816-4 standards...

Comment: @owlstead many thanks for this info. Do you know where I could find info about all these applets invlove in payments environment such as PPSE , CRs? I am new to this somain and I found about EMV and GP specs from forums. Are there any more important specs I need to farmiliar with and are there any book resources on this domain ?

Comment: I'm personally more involved in the ID business. ASN.1 is important to know. The RF part is in ISO 14443, but that's rather low level. A lot of file system cards use ISO 7816-15 (PKCS#15 is free, and the ISO standard builds upon that, so...).

Answer (score 2):

there is a free online copy of ISO/IEC 7816 parts 1 to 4 in below web page:

http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816.aspx

Answer (score 1):

FCI is defined in the ISO 7816-4 standard (Identification cards — Integrated circuit
cards — Part 4: Organization, security and commands for interchange), which can be purchased from ISO or alternatively from the standardization organization within your country. Non-normative information can be found on the internet of course.

Answer (score 1):

Hopebelow details help you to undestand FCI:

1. Terminal sends command (C-APDU) to card for application selection and application is selcted by the terminal
2. Card responds with FCI (File control Information) in R-APDU. This basically has the details about the selected application.
   Tag 6F: File Control Information (FCI) Template
   Tag A5: File Control Information (FCI) Proprietary Template

Tag 50: Application Label: 56495341 — name of the application

Tag 87: Application Priority Indicator: 01 — Application Priority Indicator

Tag 5F2D: Language Preference: 7275656E — the preferred «communication language».

Tag 9F38: Processing Options Data Object List (PDOL): 9F1A02 — the PDOL object. (available in Visa card/not in Mastercard) In this tag, card tells the terminal about the details or tags it requires to do further processing of the transaction.

Tag BF0C: File Control Information (FCI) Issuer Discretionary Template

Tag 9F5A: Application Program Identifier: 6006430643 — specific tag of  PS, in this case describing the card’s regional affiliation.